# Writing scalars into file

Tags: ios, ios5, nsarray, plist

I have an array of the following objects:

```
@interface SACameraLocation : NSObject
{
    NSInteger locId;
    NSString *name;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    NSInteger speed;
    NSInteger shootingMode;
    NSInteger side;
}
```

Then I'm trying to write array to plist file:

```
if([arr writeToFile:path atomically:YES])
    NSLog(@"Write OK");
else
    NSLog(@"Write Fail");
```

This fails I guess due to scalar objects. What is the easiest way to serialize/deserialize such an objects to the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the docs for `NSArray writeToFile:atomically:`:

> If the array’s contents are all property list objects (NSString, NSData, NSArray, or NSDictionary objects), the file written by this method can be used to initialize a new array with the class method arrayWithContentsOfFile: or the instance method initWithContentsOfFile:. This method recursively validates that all the contained objects are property list objects before writing out the file, and returns NO if all the objects are not property list objects, since the resultant file would not be a valid property list.

You can't write an array of custom objects. This is why it fails. You can have your class conform to the `NSCoding` protocol and implement the two required methods. Then you can convert your objects to `NSData` using `NSKeyedArchiver`. Or you can encode the whole array at once using an archiver, then write out the one `NSData` object.

One other option would be to convert your object to an `NSDictionary` and write out an array of those dictionaries.